# How to check user existed or not in `MongoDB` using `meteorjs`

Tags: meteor

How to check duplicate users are not allowed into ***MongoDB*** using `meteorjs`

Answer (score 0):

If using the built-in Meteor Accounts system, uniqueness of usernames and email addresses is [guaranteed](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users). You can `try/catch` a thrown error.